# Separar datos de una columna por comas SQL Server 2018

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-management

Tengo una consulta de una funcion split que me trae estos datos:

[image: split]

Me gustaria usar estos valores como parametro por lo que ahora debo convertir estos datos al siguiente formato

```
val
10000,10002,10004,10005
```

¿Como puedo hacer esto? vi que se podia realizar usando COALESCE() pero no se como usarlo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función STRING_AGG está disponible en versiones recientes de SQL Server (2017 y posteriores) y en algunas otras bases de datos, pero no en todas. Si estás usando una versión anterior de SQL Server o una base de datos que no admite STRING_AGG, puedes usar una solución alternativa para concatenar los valores.

```
SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
      SELECT ',' + CAST(val AS VARCHAR(50))
      FROM tabla
      FOR XML PATH('')
    ),
    1,
    1,
    ''
  ) AS valores_separados_por_comas
```

En este ejemplo, asumo que los valores están almacenados en una tabla llamada "tabla" y que la columna que contiene los valores se llama "val". La consulta utiliza la función FOR XML PATH('') para concatenar los valores como una cadena XML y luego utiliza la función STUFF para eliminar la primera coma de la cadena resultante.

Otra solucion es usar GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(columna SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM tabla;
```

Donde "columna" es el nombre de la columna de la tabla que deseas separar por comas y "tabla" es el nombre de la tabla que contiene la columna.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(nombre SEPARATOR ',') 
FROM clientes;
```

Answer (score 1):

Para mostrar los valores separados por comas, puedes utilizar la función STRING_AGG en SQL.

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(val, ',') AS valores_separados_por_comas
FROM tabla
```

En este ejemplo, asumo que los valores están almacenados en una tabla llamada "tabla" y que la columna que contiene los valores se llama "val". La función STRING_AGG se utiliza para concatenar todos los valores separados por comas.

La salida seria esta

```
valores_separados_por_comas
----------------------------
1000048,100002,100004,100005
```

Comment: Al querer usar la funcion String_Agg me marca este error " 'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name."

Comment: Añadi otrarespuesta

Comment: Añadí dos respuestas espero alguna logre funcionarte